# Android Studio Project can't find file in raw folder

Tags: android, kotlin, react-google-maps-api

I am trying to style my map that i hace implemented in my application. The map is working fine, but when i tried to put a style on it, it produces an error.

These are the lines that are relevant to the problem:

```
fun MapViewContainer(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, currentLatLng: LatLng) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val mapView = remember {
        MapView(context).apply {
            onCreate(Bundle())
            getMapAsync { googleMap ->
                googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(currentLatLng).title("Localització Actual"))
                googleMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
                googleMap.uiSettings.isZoomGesturesEnabled = true
                googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(), res.raw.map_style))
```

there are some parameters more, but those work fine. The problem is that it says there is an unresolved reference to res.raw.map_style, but that file does exist.
I include an image:

[image of the structure of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba4yv.png)

I hace tried to rebuild and reset Android Studio, but nothing seems to work. If someone can provide a solution, i would be very grateful. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Use it like  googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(), R.raw.map_style)

Instead of res.raw You should use R.raw

Comment: Then it says that the undefined reference is in the R

Comment: @MarcExpositoFrancisco You have to import class `package.name.R`.

Comment: import R package .As per your provided image seems your package name is com.airmon.app .Therefore try to use it like com.airmon.app.R.raw.map_style

Comment: Thanks, its working now!! Dumb mistake by me, i thought that import was already there

Answer (score -1):

It's missing the closing parenthesis for the setMapStyle method and the closing brace for the lambda expression passed to getMapAsync. Also wrap the setMapStyle call in a try-catch block to handle any exceptions.

Comment: its all closed, but i didn't include that part of the code cause it works fine. And by the try and catch, no exception pop off, its just the unresolved reference problem